# Wordpress Permalink with #more-63

Tags: php, wordpress

in my website with wordpress CMS I set Permalink to localhost/wordpress/?p=123 
as default

and in my posts there are Read More buttons to go to the single pages

the problem is that when I click on a Read More button, in the address bar it shows something like this ?p=63#more-63

why is that #more-63 there?

how can I change it to showing just ?p=63 ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found this post on WordPress Support that should help you:

> By default WordPress will add the '#more-' after your posts
>   permalinks. It enables people to skip to the rest of the article if
>   they have read the excerpt.
>
> To remove that, you need to add the following to your functions.php
>
> ```
> function removeReadMoreHash($link) {
>    $offset = strpos($link, '#more-');
>    if ($offset) {
>     $end = strpos($link, '"',$offset);
>    }
>    if ($end) {
>     $link = substr_replace($link, '', $offset, $end-$offset);
>    }
>    return $link;
> }
> add_filter('the_content_more_link', 'removeReadMoreHash');
> ```
>
> That should do the trick.

http://wordpress.org/support/topic/excerpt-link

Comment: thank you phocks.It didn't work but helped me find the answer.